# iPhone: viewWillAppear is not called for UIView

Tags: iphone

I have created an UIView in my iPhone app. I want to handle something when user closes or opens when UIView is present as current screen. I thought, i can do this under `viewWillAppear:`. But, `viewWillAppear:` is not called in UIView. Does it work only on UIViewController? How can i handle `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` for an UIView?

**Update:** UIView what I created everything through program, not in .xib.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you present and close UIView?Is it some button action or something else. what is the size of view.[btw these delegates methods wont be called as @James has answered].

Comment: Close/launch by pressing device home button. Ok, thanks if it is not possible. Can i atleast find the current UIView in "applicationDidEnterBackground" when user presses Home button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your message I infer that you wrote your `viewWillAppear:` method on the `UIView` class. As you suspect, that method is part of `[UIViewController]`[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW46), not `[UIView]`[2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) therefore it only gets called on the `UIViewController`.

You should connect the property view of the `UIViewController` to the `UIView` object in the interface builder and then implement that method in the `UIViewController`. 
If your view is created in response to an user action,

**Update** for your update:
You should tag the views either in code (`view.tag=1`) or IB. 
Then you can do `if (self.window.rootViewController.view.tag == 1) { ... }` from your delegate (assuming you are looking for the view of the controller who is the rootController, otherwise post more details).
It's even better if you define constants on one place instead writing `1` as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

These delegate methods are called every time the superview is presented to the screen and should be implemented in the UIViewControllers.

The gotcha is that these methods aren't called when subviews are presented on the screen, so your superview-view-controller will have to respond to these events accordingly.

You can find more information in [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866666/push-viewcontroller-using-uinavigationcontroller-sometimes-calls-viewdidappear-a).

Answer (score 1):

If you study the documentation for `UIView` and `UIViewController` what you will find is `-(void)viewWillAppear:animated:` is a method of `UIViewController` and not of `UIView`, so in order to use it, it must be implemented by subclassing `UIViewController`. Generally for best practice if you want to follow MVC, any functionality that does not pertain to the view itself should be delegated to the view controller and not be in the body of your `UIView` subclass.

Create a new view controller with xib file, and then link your custom view class to the view in your xib file.